# MySQL and PHP : How to arrange data from below example

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Code is below,

The Table has in MySQL database

[image]

Actually ,

Unique Item Group ID has **3**(which are 101, 102 and 103)
Total Item Group ID has 23 Which are

101 =**10**,

102=**5** and

103=**8**

Total = 23

Total Every Group ID (10 or 5 or 8) number divided by Unique Group(3).

**round(10/3) = 3, round(5/3) = 2 and round(8/3)=3**

In Output At first 101 will come sequentially 3 times then 102  sequentially 2 times and 102  sequentially 3 times , Again will maintain above ratio still print all data.

Output Will be Like below Image

[image]

Please any help to give answer using MySQL OR PHP Code,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `item` order by(item_group_id)");

echo "<table><tr><th>ITEM GROUP ID</th><th>ITEM NAME</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 ehco "<tr><td>";
 echo $row['item_group_id'] 
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['item_name'];

 echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/454e2/2)

Comment: can you either make a sqlfiddle with your data, or post plain text instead of images so we can cut and paste into a fiddle?

Comment: ok i am doing @Barmar

Comment: I made it sqlfiddle.Please help me @Barmar

Comment: What is the URL of the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a 2-dimensional array, where the first dimension is the item group IDs, the 2nd dimension is the item names:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $group_id = $row['item_group_id'];
    if (isset($data[$group_id])) {
        $data[$group_id]['names'][] = $row['item_name'];
        $data[$group_id]['count']++;
    } else {
        $data[$group_id] = array('names' => array($row['item_name']), 'count' => 1);
    }
}
```

Then process each of these sub-arrays in groups, until you've processed everything:

```
$divisor = count($data);
while (!empty($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $group_id => &$subarray) {
        $group_size = max(round($subarray['count']/$divisor), 1);
        $group = array_splice($subarray['names'], 0, $group_size);
        foreach ($group as $name) {
            echo "<tr><td>$group_id</td><td>$name</td></tr>";
        }
        if (empty($subarray['names'])) {
            unset($data[$group_id]);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/6Bijtr)

Comment: $data[$group_id]['names'][] = $row['item_name']; Above line see error  Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Oops, didn't initialize that element correctly. Fixed.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_name` varchar(201) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

Comment: (1, 'item name 01', 101),
(2, 'item name 02', 101),
(3, 'item name 03', 101),
(4, 'item name 04', 101),
(5, 'item name 05', 101),
(6, 'item name 06', 102),
(7, 'item name 07', 102),
(8, 'item name 08', 101),
(9, 'item name 09', 101),
(10, 'item name 10', 101),
(11, 'item name 11', 103),
(12, 'item name 12', 102),
(13, 'item name 13', 103),
(14, 'item name 14', 102),
(15, 'item name 15', 102),
(16, 'item name 16', 103),
(17, 'item name 17', 103),
(18, 'item name 18', 103),
(19, 'item name 19', 103),
(20, 'item name 20', 103),
(21, 'item name 21', 101),
(22, 'item name 22', 103),

Comment: Sorry! I can't understand

Comment: Comments don't have any formatting, so code is hard to read there. If you want to post large code and data, edit your question.

Comment: I thought you said you made a sqlfiddle. Post the URL of it.

Comment: You accepted the answer -- does that mean it's working, or do I need to test it more?

Comment: Your Solution is Awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: All data don't come when increase(insert) data row, please check again the code if you don't mind. Check from the link sqlfiddle.com/#!2/454e2/2 @Barmar

Comment: I was missing a `}` character. I just fixed that and tested it with your data, it works. See the demo.

Comment: Please see the link, All data does not come properly, missing 4 data http://ideone.com/GUUnq8.  Actually I want to arrange properly flowing you and my edited code. Please see the link http://ideone.com/wFsH62.

Comment: Besides, please take the file and please check my code. Please go the link and download it. http://www.mediafire.com/download/wakapo00c7wc1ie/arrange.zip         I am really sorry! I think that i am doing waste your valuable time.

Comment: Found the problem. Sometimes `round($subarray['count']/$divisor)` is zero, and it doesn't remove anything from the array and gets into an infinite loop. I added `max(..., 1)` to ensure that it always makes progress.

Answer (score -3):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT item_group_id,item_name  FROM `item` order by(item_group_id)");

echo "<table><tr><th>ITEM GROUP ID</th><th>ITEM NAME</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 ehco "<tr><td>";
 echo $row['item_group_id'] 
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['item_name'];

 echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please read the question again , i think that you don't understand the question.@chikara